# How to get mouse in and out to work from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Please take a look at these 2 demos:

http://jsfiddle.net/fVbeV/

and

http://jsfiddle.net/8uPWG/

In demo 1 if you hover over the gray rectangle you get the alert "in" and when you hover out you get the alert "out" in Chrome. But in Firefox you get the alert "in" once and never "out" or "in" on subsequent hovers.

I can I get this to work in Firefox?

**Demo 1:**

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background:#ccc; width:728px; height:90px;">Hello World</div>

var $ = parent.jQuery,
    div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

if($ !== undefined) {
    $(div).on('mouseenter', function() {
        alert('in');        
    });
    $(div).on('mouseleave', function() {
        alert('out');        
    });
}
```

**Demo 2:**

```
<iframe src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/8uPWG/show/" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not related to the question per se... Why not replace `div = document.getElementById('myDiv')` with `$div = $('#myDiv')` and then refer to the `$div` object later, i.e. `$div.on(...)`.

Comment: @Terry that won't work: http://jsfiddle.net/8uPWG/1/ Since the jQuery belongs to the parent document, jQuery seraches that parent for an elemtn with id myDiv which doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I stand corrected :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").mouseenter(function(){
       alert("mouseneter"); 
    });
     $("iframe").mouseleave(function(){
       alert("mouseleave"); 
    });
});
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/zF4Q3/

Comment: I have to have the JS in the iframed page not the parent document because this will eventually be an ad served on various sites over which I do not have control over.

Comment: it will also work in iframe, replace your JS codes with that i provided. Bu you have to import jquery into your iframe.